# How do I adjust these images displayed on gridlayout?

Tags: java, android, layout

I've displayed on a gridlayout 4 direction bottons trying to make a "game control panel" like this:

[image]

The game is made, but the trouble is with the "game panel", that's looks very small on big devices like a tablet:

[image]

How can i make the buttons to be displayed filling the parent?, my xml code is this, i've made a custom layout called square layout to display the game:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:padding="10dp">

</*packages*/SquareLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/square"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    //gameview
<//*packages*/SquareLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/afgergg"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/up"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/down"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_left" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right" />
        </GridLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Could easily treat this like a 3x3 grid with 5 dummy views
i.e Replace your grid layout with

```
<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <View  android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/up"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up" />
        <View  android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_left" />
        <View  android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <View  android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/down"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down" />
        <View  android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Alternately you could use the table layout. Note: you might wanna add margins etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can set width and height of `GridLayout`'s children like this.It will be at same size on every device.

```
   int mDesiredWidth = 70; 
   int mDesiredHeight= 70; 
   for (int i = 0; i < mGridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = (GridLayout.LayoutParams) mGridLayout
                .getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams();
        params.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        params.width = Math.round (mDesiredWidth* getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        params.height = Math.round  (mDesiredHeight* getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    }
```